# state change in React resets input fields and other DOM elements

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a filter bar that expands when you toggle it. When expanded it shows a list of filter items that can be selected, and the idea is to show the selected items somewhere on the screen by running for example:

```
appliedFilterItems.map(filter => div {filter} div )
```

Now everytime you select a filter the filterbar resets back to non expanded mode, and apparently every time there is a state change in redux then all DOM elements resets back to their original class names, and the weird thing is none are connected to redux state.

I can't figure out what causes this DOM resetting.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import shortid from "shortid";
// this is rendered inside AdminDashboard from Routes
export default class FilterOptions extends Component {
  applyFilter(e) {
    e.persist();
    const { actions } = this.props;
    actions.setFilterInState(e);
    actions.toggleFilter(e);
  }

  render() {
    const { filterOptions, appliedFilters, actions } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="filter-wrapper">
        {appliedFilters.length ? (
          <div className="selected-filter-items-wrapper">
            <button onClick={() => actions.clearFilters()}>clear</button>
            {appliedFilters.map(filter => {
              return (
                <div className="selected-filter-item" key={shortid.generate()}>
                  {filter}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}

        <div className="filter-options">
          {filterOptions.map(option => (
            <div
              onClick={e => this.applyFilter(e)}
              className="filter-option"
              key={shortid.generate()}
            >
              {option.name}
              <span className="filter-option-arrow-icon fa fa-chevron-down" />
              <div className="filter-option-list-container">
                {option.data.map(filterOption => (
                  <div className="filter-item" key={shortid.generate()}>
                    <input type="checkbox" className="filter-input" />
                    {filterOption}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


--- REDUCER ----
import stateData from "../State";
import actionTypes from "../actionTypes";

const initState = () => {
  return { ...stateData, appliedFilters: [] };
};

const setFilterState = (filterValue, state) => {
  const appliedFilters = state.appliedFilters.slice();
  const filterItemIndex = appliedFilters.indexOf(filterValue);

  if (filterItemIndex === -1) {
    return { ...state, appliedFilters: appliedFilters.concat(filterValue) };
  }
  appliedFilters.splice(filterItemIndex, 1);
  return { ...state, appliedFilters };
};

export default function(state = initState(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.TOGGLE_FILTER: {
      const event = action.payload;
      let filterOptionEl = event.target;

      if (filterOptionEl.classList.contains("filter-option-arrow-icon")) {
        filterOptionEl = filterOptionEl.parentNode;
      }

      if (filterOptionEl.classList.contains("filter-option")) {
        const iconEl = filterOptionEl.childNodes[1];
        const filterOptionsListContainerEl = filterOptionEl.childNodes[2];

        if (iconEl.classList.contains("fa-times")) {
          iconEl.className = "filter-option-arrow-icon fa fa-chevron-down";
        } else {
          iconEl.className = "filter-option-arrow-icon fa fa-times";
        }

        filterOptionEl.classList.toggle("active");
        filterOptionsListContainerEl.classList.toggle("active");

        /*         return {...state, filterOpen: !this.state.filterOpen}
         */
      }
      return state;
    }

    case actionTypes.SET_FILTER_IN_STATE: {
      const event = action.payload;
      const filterOptionEl = event.target;

      let filterValue = "";

      if (filterOptionEl.classList.contains("filter-item")) {
        filterOptionEl.firstChild.checked = !filterOptionEl.firstChild.checked;

        filterValue = filterOptionEl.textContent.replace(/\s/g, "");

        return setFilterState(filterValue, state);
      }

      if (filterOptionEl.classList.contains("filter-input")) {
        filterValue = filterOptionEl.nextSibling.wholeText.replace(/\s/g, "");
        return setFilterState(filterValue, state);
      }

      return state;
    }
}


----- ROUTES
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { state } from "./reducers/state";
import "./styles/app.scss";

import * as actions from "./actions";

import AdminDashboard from "./AdminDashboard";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) };
}

@connect(
  state,
  mapDispatchToProps
)
class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    const { productView, filterOpen } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <HashRouter basename="/">
            <div className="parent-view-container">
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  path="/pm/:id"
                  render={props => (
                    <AdminDashboard {...props} {...this.props} />
                  )}
                />
                />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Hard to say without more code. But I tend to believe that  when you said non expanding means in fact removed from DOM and therefore all internal state from components are lost, as they re remounted when redisplayed.

Comment: If I disable rendering but allow state change then no problems, also I can notice there is a flickering on the screen.

Comment: Yeah more code needed. Show the render method and the code that changes the state and inputs.

Comment: I added some code now

Comment: As you can see in the reducer am doing         filterOptionEl.classList.toggle("active");
filterOptionsListContainerEl.classList.toggle("active"); , but that becomes reset after state change

Comment: @nubinub please check now